# How to mark candle after next candle will form (after results will happen)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to this code and maybe my question will look like stupid but still need to know.

I am trying to make indicator to plot on chart , I will give an example in attachment.

[image]

assuming there is a setup with inside bar. how to mark that white candle as mother candle if next candle :
1)will be inside bar
2) only body would be in side previous candle
3) more candles inside  that first one and etc.
question, which function I should use to mark that particular candle if and only after event will happen?

I tried expr2 and expr3 and expr4 t ? expr1 : na

I tried with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Qs3.png) prev candles but its not that, the issue is only about the event after which I'll need to mark prev candle not in advance.
example No.2 [image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa6vW.png)

Comment: sorry, can't guess with what toolkit on which programming language you're working. this is all a bit mysterious... Please **edit** your question to state in much more detail with what you're working.

Comment: Sorry, thought its all about the same :) its Pine Script for trading view chart editing.

Comment: … Please **edit** your question …

Comment: which command or syntax to use , to make scrip showing/marking on the chart live and on history mother bar (meaning after next bar is created and IF this newly created bar is creates as inside bar or several inside bars in a row). attach also chart with question hope more clear. I cant add attachment in this comment. So I added as No.2 image in y first question part.

Comment: @MarcusMüller , can you help me with my issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is script you can start with, I suggest you read the user guide first to understand it and further develop it to your needs.

```
//@version=5
indicator("outside bar",overlay=true)
var float inside_bar_high = high
var float inside_bar_low = low
var float outside_bar_high = high
var float outside_bar_low = low

inside_bar = high<= outside_bar_high and low>= outside_bar_low
if (inside_bar)    // If there is a new inside bar, update the high and low price
    inside_bar_high := high
    inside_bar_low := low

if not(inside_bar)
    outside_bar_high := high
    outside_bar_low := low

last_bar_outside=inside_bar

plotshape(last_bar_outside, shape=shape.arrowdown,location=location.abovebar,offset=-1,color=color.red)
```

Comment: I really do read all possible guides but to say the truth I wanted so solve it faster. plus I only started coding this langue like 3 days ago and too much questions no one to ask, no friends programmers etc.  :) so I thought I need professional help 
So I sincerely thank you

Comment: Still have a question, I reviewed and retried to understand it but still have same question in my mind. I understand what you've wrote, but how to add additional variable for more complex setup. The same example as it was before, but how to find mother bar + inside bar or several bars, but now inside bars can be different (with the wick  which can extend below or above previous bar /"mother bar" but candle/bar body closes inside previous bar ?
I wrote like this,not helping 
inside_bar = high<= outside_bar_high and low>= outside_bar_low and open<= outside_bar_high and close>= outside_bar_low

Comment: if you are only interested in the body of the candle then perhaps a simple modification
```top = open> close? open: close
bot = open> close? close:open

inside_bar = top<= outside_bar_high and bot>= outside_bar_low```

Comment: Not only in the body there are several requirements:
to mark mother_bar/outside_bar  (after which next bars counts:
1) if inside bar open and close are in the previous bar(mother_bar/outside_bar) high and low. 
2) if inside bar high< than outside bar and low>than outside bar

Comment: I added one more print screen

Comment: you can add the conditions that you think apply, you have enough to go on